# How to make the Spheres able to deal damage to eachother?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Want to make my Spheres able to damage each other

Have tried to get the component of the other object

Health script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public class Hitpoints 
{

    private int health;
    public  int healthMax;

    public Hitpoints(int health)
    {

        this.health = health;

    }

    public int GetHealth()
    {
        return health;
    }

    public float GetHealthPercent()
    {
        return (float)health / healthMax;

    }



    public void Damage(int damageAmount)
    {

        health -= damageAmount;
        if (health < 0)
        {
            health = 0;
        }
    }

    public void Heal(int healAmount)
    {
        health += healAmount;
        if (health > healthMax)
        {
            health = healthMax;
        }

    }
}
```

Damage script

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class Detect_Blue : MonoBehaviour
{

    Hitpoints hitpoints = new Hitpoints(100);

    bool onetime = false;
    public float radius;
    public Vector3 direction = new Vector3(2, 2, 2);

    private void Start()
    {


        Debug.Log("Health: " + hitpoints.GetHealth());
        InvokeRepeating("DetectEnemy", 4f, 2f);
    }


    private void DetectEnemy()
    {

        var hitColliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(direction, radius);

        for (var i = 0; i < hitColliders.Length; i++)
        {
            if (hitColliders[i].CompareTag("Player"))
            {
                if (!onetime)
                {

                    onetime = true;
                    print(hitColliders[i].tag);

                    InvokeRepeating("Hello", 1, 1);
                }

            }

// collect information on the hits here
        }

    }

    private void Hello()
    {
        var hitColliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(direction, radius);
        for (var i = 0; i < hitColliders.Length; i++)
        {
            if (hitColliders[i].CompareTag("Player"))
            {
                hitColliders[i].GetComponent<Hitpoints>().Damage(10);
            }




            Debug.Log("Damaged: " +  hitColliders[i].GetComponent<Hitpoints>().GetHealth());
            if (hitpoints.GetHealth() == 0)
            {
                Destroy(gameObject);

            }


        }
    }
}
```

> ArgumentException: GetComponent requires that the requested component 'Hitpoints' derives from MonoBehaviour or Component or is an interface.
>   UnityEngine.Component.GetComponent[Hitpoints] () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Component.bindings.cs:42)
>   Detect_Blue.Hello () (at Assets/Detect_Blue.cs:57)

Comment: You want to know why the error is happening or some other ways to handle the issue? As the error message says add MonoBehaviour interface to Hitpoint.cs. Also you can use colliders and Oncollisionenter method to detect collision

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `GetComponent<T>` on a game object, the type of `T` should inherit from monobehaviour.
(Since Monobehavior are components for game-object, and you are trying to get a component)

To fix this, just simply use the `hitpoints` you have already created in `Detect_Blue`.

```
Debug.Log("Damaged: " +  hitColliders[i].GetComponent<Hitpoints>().GetHealth());
```

will become

```
Debug.Log("Damaged: " +  hitColliders[i].GetComponent<Detect_Blue>().hitpoints.GetHealth());
```

likewise for `hitColliders[i].GetComponent<Hitpoints>().Damage(10);`, it should be:

```
hitColliders[i].GetComponent<Detect_Blue>().hitpoints.Damage(10);
```

**Alternatively**,
you can just simply make `Hitpoints` inherit from Monobehavior and attach the script to the respective gameObject.
Though in your case, the first solution will be more feasible.

Also, you can use [`OnCollisionEnter`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html) to detect when the balls enter collision with another object.